# How to make python function always unbound even assigned to a class attribute

Tags: python, function

Having the following code, what can I do with the 'foo' function to make it unbound in any case even if it is assigned to class attribute? Overriding __get__ doesn't help - as far as I understand because it is not used when function is absent from __dict__ of an instance (it is so in case of class attributes).
But what else can be done here?

```
def foo(x):
    print(x)

def foo_get(self, obj, type=None):
    return foo

foo.__get__ = foo_get

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = foo
class B(object):
    f = foo


a = A()

print(a.f)               #<function foo at 0x2321d10>
print(a.f.__get__(a, A)) #<function foo at 0x2321d10>

b = B()

print(b.f)               #<bound method B.foo of <__main__.B object at 0x23224d0>>
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I need that to monkey patch builtin thread.start_new_thread in such way that there is no difference between any usage of original vergion and monkey patched one. Now there is, when I assign start_new_thread to class attribute(waitress library does that) then use it. Original version works, because it has type build-in function always, and monkey-patch doesn't as it becomes bound.

Comment: but `thread.start_new_thread` isn't a method on a class. it's `<built-in function start_new_thread>`. if you want to replace it you just need to assign to `thread.start_new_thread` and give it a normal function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want [@staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

`foo = staticmethod(foo)`

You can also define `__get__` on a callable class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self

    def __call__(self, x):
        print(x)

foo = Foo()

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = foo
class B(object):
    f = foo


foo(1) # 1
a = A()

a.f(1) # 1
print(a.f)               #<function foo at 0x2321d10>
print(a.f.__get__(a, A)) #<function foo at 0x2321d10>

b = B()
b.f(1) # 1


print(b.f)               #<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fa8c260be10>
```

It's one extra level of indentation and a few extra lines of code, but that's how it can be done, if it's important.

Comment: I've tried staticmethod, but that leads to another problem: I can't use foo by itself foo(1), I get
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable

Comment: Updated. As for monkeypatching a stdlib function... be careful. Are you whatever you're trying to do can't be done elsewhere?

Comment: That can't be done elsewhere as I'm dealing with python debugger and debugger needs newly created threads to be traced and for that monkey-patching start_new_thread is realy the only way.